# Elixir enumerable chunks: How to partition a list into sublists partitioned according to multiples of n

Tags: elixir

Let's say I have a list of *strictly increasing* integers in Elixir, that I want to break up into sublists whenever the number becomes greater than a multiple of 5. I'm trying to use chunk_by but I'm getting this:

```
Enum.chunk_by([300, 301, 304, 305, 306, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 
315, 316, 317, 319, 320], fn(x) -> rem(x, 5) == 0 end)

 [
  [300],
  [301, 304],
  [305],
  [306, 309],
  [310],
  [311, 312, 313, 314],
  [315],
  [316, 317, 319],
  [320]
]
```

when what I really want is:

```
[
  [300, 301, 304],
  [305, 306, 309],
  [310, 311, 312, 313, 314],
  [315, 316, 317, 319],
  [320]
]
```

I basically need the list broken up on "5-boundaries" but **without** the boundaries themselves creating separate lists. How do I go about this?

Comment: Not sure I understand this. What output do you expect for `[7, 10, 16, 4, 6, 19, 8, 13, 3, 14, 11, 17, 20, 18, 2, 15, 1, 9, 5, 12]`?

Comment: the list is strictly increasing....I'll highlight it in the question.

Comment: Will you always have all of the numbers?  Or for example could you have `300, 302` (missing `301`) ?

Comment: @Tyler yes indeed there may be missing values. If my question wasn't clear enough ("irregularly spaced") I'll edit.

Comment: let me rewrite the question a little bit to make that clearer.

Comment: Yeah, I'd suggest modifying the example to have missing values.

Comment: duly rewritten...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return `div(x, 5)` and not `rem(x, 5) == 0`. As soon as the result of `div(x, 5)` changes it means the value should be in a new list.

```
iex(1)> Enum.chunk_by(300..320, fn x -> div(x, 5) end)
[
  [300, 301, 302, 303, 304],
  [305, 306, 307, 308, 309],
  [310, 311, 312, 313, 314],
  [315, 316, 317, 318, 319],
  [320]
]
iex(2)> Enum.chunk_by([200, 201, 204, 207, 220, 226, 228], fn x -> div(x, 5) end)
[[200, 201, 204], [207], [220], [226, 228]]
```

Comment: aha! My mistake was incorrectly to assume that the function argument in Enum.chunk_by had to return true or false. I now see the (obvious in hindsight) error of my ways.

Comment: curveball: what if the numbers were real numbers? Truncate them first I guess?

Comment: Yeah, `div(trunc(x), 5)` or `trunc(x / 5)`.